# How would I add the option to give the user the ability to add their own image to a picture puzzle game using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to give a user the ability to use their own image for my game (a picture puzzle game) rather than using the default one which I have uploaded myself.

So for example, the game should prompt the user with the option of 'use default image' or 'browse for your own image' to use. I have absolutely no idea where to start with this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you think of some code? If so, add it to your post, so that we can have a better idea.

Comment: Are you in control of the web server in the back-end?

Comment: We would love to help you, but we need your code so far

Comment: It's just a notepad file, I'm doing it for an assignment, I have the CSS files, HTML etc. These are the picture codes I have so far:

"$( document ).ready(function() {

   startPicturePuzzle("PICNAME.jpg");
   
  });"

"$('#restart').on('click', function(){
     $('#picturePuzzle').empty();
     var picturePath = $(picture).attr('src');
     picture = new Image();
     startPicturePuzzle(picturePath);
    });"

"$(picture)
    .load(function() {"

Things like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default image, and let the user select a file using a file `input`. If the user selects a file, read it and convert it to a URL by using `FileReader`. And use this URL. Try it:

```js
var defaultImg = 'http://i.imgur.com/hMyn5YW.jpg',
    imgToUse = defaultImg;

document.getElementById('defaultBtn').addEventListener('click', startPuzzle);

document.getElementById('customImg').addEventListener('change', getCustomImg);

function getCustomImg(){
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            imgToUse = e.target.result;
            startPuzzle();
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    } else {
        alert('No file was added');
    }
}

function startPuzzle(){
    document.body.innerHTML = '<img src="'+imgToUse+'"/>';
}
```

```html
<button id="defaultBtn">Use default image</button>

<p>or choose an image from your computer:</p>
<input type='file' id="customImg" />
```

jQuery version:

```js
var defaultImg = 'http://i.imgur.com/hMyn5YW.jpg',
    imgToUse   = defaultImg;

$('#defaultBtn').on('click', startPuzzle);

$('#customImg').on('change', getCustomImg);

function getCustomImg(){
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            imgToUse = e.target.result;
            startPuzzle();
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    } else {
        alert('No file was added');
    }
}

function startPuzzle(){
    $('body').html('<img src="'+imgToUse+'"/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="defaultBtn">Use default image</button>

<p>or choose an image from your computer:</p>
<input type='file' id="customImg" />
```

Comment: Blex, thank you so much! I'm going to try my best to implement that, and change it into my own code. I was wondering in case I have a question or difficulty with this, do you have an email address or a Facebook account I could reach you on? I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: @JordanPalmer If you need more help, come back here.

Comment: Blex, it's come up with a lot of code, the game hasn't loaded and I haven't any clue what's gone on. It's displayed the buttons, but nothing more. Is there a way to upload a picture on here so I can show?

Comment: @JordanPalmer You can upload a picture to [imgur](http://imgur.com/), or even better, create a zip file with your files, and send it to something like [Fast files](http://www.fast-files.com/).